# Change value of column based on specific id in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below sorted dataframe and I want to set the last value of each **id** in the **id column** to **0**

```
id value
1   500
1   50
1   36
2   45
2   150
2   70
2   20
2   10
```

I am able to set the last value of the entire **id column** to 0 using `df['value'].iloc[-1] = 0`. How can I set the last value of both **id : 1** and **id : 2** to get the below output.

```
id value
1   500
1   50
1   0
2   45
2   150
2   70
2   20
2   0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and keep last to get the last row of each id. Use the `index` of these rows and set the value to 0

```
df.loc[df['id'].drop_duplicates(keep='last').index, 'value'] = 0

print(df)
   id  value
0   1    500
1   1     50
2   1      0
3   2     45
4   2    150
5   2     70
6   2     20
7   2      0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 df.loc[~df.id.duplicated('last'),'value']=0
```

**Broken down**

```
    m=df.id.duplicated('last')
    
    df.loc[~m,'value']=0




id  value
0   1    500
1   1     50
2   1      0
3   2     45
4   2    150
5   2     70
6   2     20
7   2      0
```

**How it works**

```
m=df.id.duplicated('last')# Selects the last duplicated in column id

~m reverses that and hence last duplicated becomes true

df.loc[~m,'value']# loc accessor allows us to reach the True value in the nominated column to write with 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `numpy` here is a fast solution:

```
import numpy as np

# Recreate example
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id":[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
    "value": [500,50,36,45,150,70,20,10]
})
# Solution
df["value"] = np.where(~df.id.duplicated(keep="last"),0,df["value"].to_numpy())
```

Comment: I also want to set value to binary 1 if id : 1 > 100 and id : 2 < 100 or to binary 0 if id : 1 < 101 and id : 2 > 99. I have tried adding a new column threshold. Is there a more efficient solution and how can I achieve this without adding a new column.

rindx=df[((df['id'] == 1) & (df['value'] > 100)) | ((df['id'] == 2) & (df['value'] < 100))].index
df.loc[rindx,'threshold']= 1
rindx=df[((df['id'] == 1) & (df['value'] < 101)) | ((df['id'] == 2) & (df['value'] > 99))].index
df.loc[rindx,'threshold']= 0

Comment: Expected output:

`id value`
`1   1`
`1   0`
`1   0`
`2   1`
`2   0`
`2   1`
`2   1`
`2   0`